# Python. Error in Detecting output simple quiz

Tags: python

I have written a simple quiz using python and imported the questions using a *.csv* file. How ever the output of the program is not in the desired way as it requires an additional space and a colon to make the program understand the correct output. My suspicion is the splitting the data file. I just started learning about file handling and this is causing me some problems.

```
def quiz(number, y):
   
    quizFile = input("Please enter the name of the quiz file: ")
    quizFile = open("data.csv","r")
    quizData = quizFile.readlines()
    random.shuffle(quizData)
    questionno=1
    score=0
    questionsRight=0
    #print(type(quizData))

    print("Hey ", y.capitalize(),", Here's your first question!")
    print("\n")
    print("====== Player no.", number, y.capitalize(),"======")
    
    
    for i in range(5):
        x = quizData[i].strip()
        data = x.split(',')        
        question = data[0]
        CorrectAnswer = data[1]
        
        
        print("Question #",questionno)
        print(question)
        answer = input("What is your answer?")
        if answer.lower() == CorrectAnswer.lower():
            print("Correct!")
            score=score+1
            questionsRight=questionsRight+1
            questionno = questionno+1
        else:
            print("Incorrect.")
            print('Correct answer should be:' + CorrectAnswer)
            questionno = questionno+1
        #print()

    totalScore = (score / 5) * 100
    print("You got ",score," questions right, and a score of ",totalScore,"%.")
    return totalScore

#Main
print (" Welcome to 'How well do you know Germany'")
a=" "
b=" "
print("\n")
start = input(" press any number to Start: ")
print("\n")
print("Awesome! Let's start with your name ")
a = input("Player 1: ")
b = input("Player 2: ")
print("\n")

score1 = quiz(1, a)
score2 = quiz(2, b)

if score1 > score2:
    print(a, " has the higher score!")
elif score1 < score2:
    print(b, " has the higher score!")
else:
    print("Students are tied!")
```

Welcome to 'How well do you know Germany'

press any number to Start: 1

Awesome! Let's start with your name
Player 1: vv
Player 2: bb

Please enter the name of the quiz file: data.csv

Hey  Vv , Here's your first question!

====== Player no. 1 Vv ======
Question # 1

"What currency is used in Germany?

What is your answer?euro
Incorrect.

Correct answer should be: Euro"

Question # 2
"Which German city is known for its Oktoberfest?

Even though the answer is correct it requires a space and a " inorder for the program to make the answer correct. please help

Comment: Open your csv file as text-file and attach the first five lines to the question.

Comment: Are you sure about the line `quizFile = open("data.csv","r")`.  Maybe you wanted to do `quizFile = open(quizfile,"r")` as you are taking the name of file as input in previous lone